# OpenSSL Compile WinCE 6.0

Tags: c++, openssl, windows-ce

I am trying to compile OpenSSL 0.9.8i with windows CE SDK Toradex CE600 with reference to steps defined in the link below
[OpenSSL Compile WinCE](http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.5.2/html/CompileOpenSSLCE.html)

When running nmake -f ms\cedll.mak command getting many Link2001 Errors as below
Please Help me in resolving this errors.

```
OLDNAMES.lib(wcsdup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wcsdup
    OLDNAMES.lib(strnicmp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __strnicmp
    OLDNAMES.lib(stricmp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stricmp
    OLDNAMES.lib(setmode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __setmode
    OLDNAMES.lib(fileno.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fileno
    OLDNAMES.lib(strdup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __strdup
    OLDNAMES.lib(wcsdup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __wcsdup
    out32dll_ARMV4I\libeay32d.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 113 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\bin\x86_arm\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
    Stop.
```

Comment: It seems that it's not able to find functions from the standard C library, those should be exported by coredll.lib, can you check if it's referenced?

Comment: Do you have any updated versions/tutorial on how to build OpenSSL to Windows CE today or a release channel to get them?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add SSL/TLS support to your application and don't have specific dependencies on openSSL, you may have a look at mbedTLS:
https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls
I made a fork of an old version to build it for Windows Embedded Compact 2013:
https://github.com/VMinute/mbedtls
and it builds with almost no changes.

Comment: I have Compiled OpenSSL Successfully , But now the problem is BIO_DO_CONNECT always returns -1 in my program.